# How to create trigger and function using arguments dynamically?

Tags: postgresql

For example, I have a table with 3 columns: `a`, `b` & `c`, in the function need set one of three columns, for example:

```
insert into test (a, b, c) values (...)
```

But need call the function from trigger, for example, when update a row set `a` column to true, when insert set `b` and when delete set `c`.

I try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_test(s_a, s_b, s_c)
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test(a, b, c)
    VALUES(s_a, s_b, s_c);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

But postgres says: `s_a does not exist`.

My idea is create multiple trigger with this arguments, such as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test
    AFTER INSERT
    ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_test(true, false, false);

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_test(false, true, false);
```

My idea is create a audit table with current changes by username.

Comment: I would spend some time here [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). To start : 1) "Note that the function must be declared with no arguments even if it expects to receive some arguments specified in CREATE TRIGGER — such arguments are passed via TG_ARGV, as described below"  2) "The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null."

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you don't need to pass arguments to the trigger function. You can simply do for the INSERT :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_test()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.a = TRUE;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_test();
```

For the UPDATE trigger, you can do the same while replacing `NEW.a = TRUE` by `NEW.b = TRUE`.

PS : you can't update the `NEW` values in an `AFTER INSERT` or `AFTER UPDATE` trigger because the fields are updated in the database right after the BEFORE trigger has been executed and before the AFTER trigger is executed.